# Change header of Java web service response without having Jackson convert it

Tags: java, web-services, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm having some trouble with transfering data from and to my web service from my web application.

So i have a Java JAX-RS web service with Spring, Hibernate and Jackson. So far i've used JSON-P to get the data from the web service but now I need to do POST calls so i'm trying to switch to CORS.

The old code using JSON-P:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUsers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity getUsers(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    Set<User> list = null;
    list = userBo.getUsers();
    if (list != null) {
        return callback + "(" + list.toString() + ");";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to change the headers of the response by doing:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUsers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity getUsers(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    Set<User> list = null;
    list = userBo.getUsers();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS, POST");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
return new ResponseEntity(list.toString(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But Jackson converts the entire ResponseEntity to a JSON string. Anyone know how I can change the header without having jackson convert it all?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Response` instead of `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: Thanks i'm looking into this now. I'll post my findings once i'm done. Now that i know what to look for it seems there are a lot of topics about this.

Comment: Ok so i changed the return to:
Response.ok(result).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "file://").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS, POST").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type").build();

And changed my javascript to match and now it works. Couldn't believe the answer was so simple. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using regular HTTP Filter:

```
public class AddHeaderFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response)
            chain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);
            wrappedResponse.addHeader("myheaderName", "myHeaderValue");

        }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Even though this could also work, I used the easiest solution. But thanks to you i've learned about Filters. So thanks a lot!